# Finding corresponding value of the first column from second column in an array by using efficient method? MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, comparison

I have an array of two columns.

1st column is Time, Second Column is speed.

I am using this code to find corresponding value of time from second column. This code works fine but it make my simulation slow.

**Can someone suggest efficient way of doing it?**

```
t=T';                       % Time is in seconds
vv=vel';                    % Speed is in meter per seconds
data= [t, vv];              % both time and velocity in one array
v2 = data(dsearchn(data(:,1),t2),2);
```

Example Array:

```
0.0  0.0
2.3  0.9
3.2  1.2
4.0  1.5
4.6  1.8
5.1  2.0
5.6  2.1
6.0  2.3
6.5  2.5
6.9  2.6
7.2  2.8
7.6  2.9
7.9  3.0
8.2  3.2
8.5  3.3
8.8  3.4
9.1  3.5
9.4  3.6
9.7  3.7
10.0 3.8
10.2 3.9
10.5 4.0
10.7 4.1
11.0 4.2
11.2 4.3
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are going to do when you "choose" a value from the first column?

Comment: Basically I  would like to find the value in a second column corresponding to a value of the first column.

Comment: That doesn't answer Will's question... I highly doubt you're looking to input `2.28388327781348` as your choice? Are you using a GUI, an input box, do you want the nearest match? Do you want the next highest? What if I enter `15` or `-3`? What tolerance are you using for the match (because you have so many decimal places, this looks like a numerical accuracy trap)? It's really unclear what you're asking, please show your expected input and output for this problem. And what is your *issue*? Do you not know how to find the row, how to use the row number, how to get input, how to store output...

Comment: Sorry, i am new to matlab and finding it hard to understand some things. Also, I  choose wrong example. I am not using GUI Box.  The time column is in seconds. So choosing single digit may create a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
matrix = zeros(length(Time_Vector),2);  % initialize zero matrix
matrix(:,1) = Time_Vector;  %fill first column with time vector
matrix(:,2) = Speed_Vector;  %fill second column with speed vector

matrix(5,:)  %displays the fifth row in Command Window as (Time , Speed)
```

and then you modify the value 5 with whichever value you want

Comment: Thank you, This method is faster than dsearchn function.

Answer (score 1):

Like stated in the comments you need to define what you want to happen if your "choice" of time (1st column of data) is not contained in your matrix.

Here are a couple of example of options.  Note I made `data` a nx2 matrix from your sample.

**Exact Match Only:**  If `choice` is not in `data` then empty results.

```
results = data(data(:,1) == choice,2)
```

Example Usage:

```
>> choice = 2.3; %Time contained in data
>> results = data(data(:,1) == choice,2)
results =
    0.9000

>> choice = 2.31; %Time NOT contained in data
>> results = data(data(:,1) == choice,2)
results =
   Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

**Closest Match**: Return the closest match

```
result = data(dsearchn(data(:,1),choice),2)
```

Example Usage:

```
>> choice = 2.3; %Time contained in data
>> result = data(dsearchn(data(:,1),choice),2)
result =
    0.9000

>> choice = 2.31; %Time NOT contained in data
>> result = data(dsearchn(data(:,1),choice),2)
result =
    0.9000
```

Comment: Also see `interp1` as a way to find a value in the first column.

Comment: 'exact match' is a problem when comparing floats.